# Magento: Need a cross-browser "Continue Shopping" (back twice) button to reload current category page

Tags: javascript, magento, magento-1.7

I have added a "Continue Shopping" button to the add-to-cart success-message in magento product page. My thought was to use a simple method to step back twice in the history to return to the products category. I tried this initially:

```
onclick="window.history.go(-1); return false;"
```

This worked perfectly in Chrome and Safari, but only took FF users back one state. I tried using other js methods but always had that breakdown between browsers.

```
<a href="javascript: window.history.go(-1);">
<a href="javascript: history.back(-2);">
```

I'm not loading items using AJAX, don't understand History.js (willing to learn though), and I need some help finding a cross-browser solution for this problem.

Comment: What page are you on when the message appears, and what page are you wanting the user to go to?  Using javascript for this is a bit of a hack and might produce undesired results for the user.  I'd suggest querying the exact URL you want the user to go to, then using that in your link.

Comment: Which FF version do you have? AFAIK, "window.history.go(-2)" works for your situation in the latest FF. Hope https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history helps.

Comment: I also agree with @Axel that you may the exact URL for your suggestion, maybe a recommendation module or a fixed URL. Or simply you may store the latest category visit in the session, and then load URL in your shopping cart.

Comment: @Axel, I am on the product page, but this is after the page reloads due to adding a product. I want them to go back to the category page where they found the item but going back once will just reload the product page. By querying the exact URL do you mean using something like 'getCategoryUrl()' or creating a function to parse out the URL up to the last backslash? Thanks for the direction not to use js!

Comment: @Allen Koo, I am using the latest version FF. I did find that "window.history.go(-2)" worked, but I don't get the same page in other browsers. Thanks for the link to developer.mozilla.org, it's a great resource! As far as the session goes, do you mean I should create a php function that uses ['HTTP_REFERRER']?

Comment: If you're on the product page, try using `$this->helper('catalog/data')->getCategory()->getUrl();` in the view to get the URL of the category the product is in.

Comment: Ok, I tried @Axel's code, and if I just place it on the page it works perfectly. My problem is that I am getting lost in the syntax of loading that into the following code from CartController.php: `$message = $this->__('%s was added to your shopping cart. Click to <a href="/checkout/cart/" id="itemAdder" class="addSuccess">View Your Cart</a>.', Mage::helper('core')->escapeHtml($product->getName()));
  $continues = $this->__('<?php echo $this->helper(\'catalog/data\')->getCategory()->getUrl();?>');
                    $this->_getSession()->addSuccess($message . $continues);`

Comment: @MattTrueblood - I added a detailed answer, along with an explanation of the syntax.  Hopefully that helps you understand it better.

Comment: @MattTrueblood, As I understand, you are going to give a link to the latest category visit of the customer. As the history management is different in different browser, I do mean you can store the latest category ID in the session and get it when you generate the success message.

Comment: This sounds very powerful @AllenKoo, but I am not sure of the best way to go about doing that. Also at this point I think that my problem is trying to figure out how to best load the html that will create the link. Axel's provided a solution below that works when I load in a random spot on the page, but since I am loading it in the global_messages it doesn't seem to want to work. Could you give an example of how to store something in the session and then access it? I am a bit of a noob, but I'm assuming this would be similar to how $_POST works right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This syntax should work for your needs.

```
$category = Mage::helper('catalog/data')->getCategory();
$continues = ($category ? $this->__(' or <a href="%s">continue shopping</a>', $category->getUrl()) : '');

$message = $this->__('%s was added to your shopping cart. Click to <a href="/checkout/cart/" id="itemAdder" class="addSuccess">View Your Cart</a>%s.', Mage::helper('core')->escapeHtml($product->getName()), $continues); 

$this->_getSession()->addSuccess($message);
```

What's happening in the code:

1. Get the category
2. Check to see if the category exists, if it does, set the continue text, if not, set it to a blank value. (Using a [PHP ternary operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary))
3. Include the $continues variable in the standard message
4. Add success message to the session.

---

A quick explanation of the `$this__('Text here %s', $variable)`

This function is used by Magento for mostly text translations.

The `%s` you see used is actually replaced by the variables passed into the function.

For example, say you have this: `$this__('Hello, my name is %s', $name)`

In this case, if `$name = 'John';`, the output would be `Hello, my name is John`

You can define more than one variable also.  So if you have:
`$this__('Hello, my name is %s and I am a %s', $name, $jobtitle)`

And `$name = 'John'` and `$jobtitle = 'Farmer'`, the output would be:
`Hello, my name is John and I am a Farmer.`

The `%s` is replaced in the order the variables are defined.  So the first instance of `%s` will be replaced by the first variable, `$name`, and the second replaced by `$jobtitle`, and so on.  You can define as many variables as you want, just know that the variables need to be in a specific order.

Comment: This looks great, and your explanation was very helpful. After I put the code in though, I get an error that says "Call to undefined method Mage_Checkout_CartController::helper()" on this line `$category = $this->helper('catalog/data')->getCategory();`

Comment: I updated the code to use `Mage::helper('catalog/data')->getCategory();` instead.  Try that and see if it works.

Comment: Sorry, I copied something wrong and after fixing my error that error message is gone. But the code with the continue shopping link isn't loading into the page.

Comment: I added a little code into the third expression of $continues and it must not be finding a category.  I don't understand how this is happening though since the original code you gave me pulls the correct URL.

Comment: What template file are you making these changes to?

Comment: not making changes to a template file. changing Cart Controller.php in core\Mage\Checkout\controllers\. I know it's not the right way to do this, but I haven't had great success in creating modules so far.

Answer (score 1):

As discussed in the comments, I just provide a rough example for my proposal.

I'd like to save the category id into session, once customer visits a product category page, which means, this logic may be implemented in the product category page or its block. (latter is recommended, but it really needs to write a module and overwrite the original block.) My example will be directly implemented in template/catalog/category/view.phtml (for default theme).

```
$_category_id = $_category->getId();
Mage::getModel('core/session')->set('last_visit_category_id', $_category_id);
```

Then when you are doing an AJAX add to cart action, or redirect to shopping cart page:

```
$_category_id = Mage::getModel('core/session')->get('last_visit_category_id');
$_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_category_id);
```

Let's call the above code block as *getRecommendCategory*, you may change the logic to recommend a category for customer based on their activities.

Hope this helps.